# Full width image in android notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I need to add full width image in the notification for my application.

I do it by sending the URL in the json payload, load the bitmap and on successful image loading I show the notification.

My question is what is the best **optimum resolution of the Image**

Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

The width of your image should be equal to the width of the screen as the width of the dropdown notification bar will be the same.

In order to do that you need to do this:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
```

After doing this you can set the value of `int width` to your image.

Comment: You're incorrect. What about tablets? Tablets are much wider in screen width but the notification pull down is much narrower.